# Parse data from Excel using js-xlsx

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, excel

I am using the [js-xlsx](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx), here is a link to my [excel sheet](https://myclassbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Test.xlsx) if needed. I'm using the following code:

```
/* set up XMLHttpRequest */
var url = "Test.xlsx";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(e) {
var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

/* convert data to binary string */
var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
var arr = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] =String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
var bstr = arr.join("");

/* Call XLSX */
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});

/* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
/* Get worksheet */
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true}));
}
oReq.send();
```

In the console loge I get an output of:

```
(3) […]​0: Object { FirstName: "Mayuresh", MiddleName: "Dinkar ", LastName: "Joshi", … }​1: Object { FirstName: "Arun", MiddleName: "Vikas", LastName: "Pathak", … }​2: Object { FirstName: "Narendra", MiddleName: "Damodardas", LastName: "Modi", … }​length: 3​<prototype>: Array []
```

I'm sure not sure how to access that data. I don't know it's name to call it. I tried arr.length, but it only returned 1 and it should've returned 3. The JS files returns a length of 3, but I'm not sure where it's pulling that from. I just need some accessing that Array. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's working.  Try this to see...

```
let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
let objects = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true});
let names = objects.map(object => `${object.FirstName} ${object.LastName}`);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: I got "TypeError: workbook.map is not a function". I know it's working, I just don't know how to tap into that array

Comment: the new edit doesn't work, but let objects = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true});
  let names = objects.map(object => `${object.FirstName} ${object.LastName}`); did

Comment: yikes.  sorry, your response was so quick, i thought you were referring to the prior edit.  will fix back.  "to_json" is a really non-sensical name for that utlitly